# Wrong Sorting nomenclature and predefined variables

Tags: nomenclature

This time I'm writing my Bachelor Thesis on Uni Stuttgart. Now I got a problem. I predefined my Variables for being able to change them easily in the whole document. For example I did it like this:

```
\newcommand{\x}{L_i}
```

If I now create a list of variables by `\makenomenclature` the variables are sorted by the command. Here `\x`. Is it possible to sort it by the given Variables? Here `L_i`?
It would be very nice to have a most possible easy solution for this.
Thank you and sorry for my bad english.
Regards Manuel

Comment: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.